# How to develope micro apps for mobile (both ios and android)

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, micro-frontend, walmart-electrode

i have a react native app and another android application. i need to develop a micro app that can be integrated into both of the application . (mobile environment)

i heard about electrode react native. but i couldn't find even a Hello world application or steps to integrate into another application.

can you guys tell me a solution?

Comment: Can you specify the `integrate` you need? For example: React Native Linking can open other apps in mobile.

Comment: tag `micro-architecture` does not relate to your question. What is `micro app`?

Comment: it is like a plugin which should be able to communicate with the parent application.

Comment: Similar to the micro front end in web development , i need in mobile environment